# Smooth scrolling when clicking Anchor Link

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website that a client came to me with. He is requesting that all scroll speeds for anchors links match.

If you go to the home page here: https://www.lakeshoresup.com/ and click on Learn More under LET THE ADVENTURE BEGIN. The page scrolls down to the next section nicely.

Now if I click on Write Review next to the stars in a product (https://www.lakeshoresup.com/product/pathfinder/) it just jumps to the bottom instantly. The client wants the scroll for the first link.

First, how to I change the scroll speed?

Second, will it even work? The reviews come from a third party called Yotpo. Is it possible to change the scroll speed on this link that is embedded from third party software?

Comment: FYI, the answers don't actually give you control over scroll speed, they merely apply a default browser speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add in css a general scroll behavior for the entire website to scroll smoothly like:

```
* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both! Worked, when I searched I kept coming up with Javacript results but this was easy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use smooth scroll behavior. It's enable smooth scrolling for the whole page.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both! Worked, when I searched I kept coming up with Javacript results but this was easy!